# Odoo 14 field filter

Tags: odoo-14

I haven't been able to enable end_date field to be filtered in account.out.invoice.tree view with NO CODING but through ir.model.fields form. I tried copying end_date from account.move.line  model to account.move with no success. I have done a procedure like this in the past without an issue (related field from another model) but this time I am not being able to find the correct model-field relationship perhaps because one is at line level and the other is at a whole invoice level.

"end_date" is a field that comes from the following module:
https://github.com/OCA/account-closing/tree/14.0/account_invoice_start_end_dates

In summary: I want to be able to find invoices that have move lines with an "end_date" between a range of dates.